# Is there any use for constexpr references?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constexpr

As the title says, is there any useful case for constexpr references? Like so:

```
static const int myvar = myfunc();  // myfunc is not constexpr
constexpr const int& myref = myvar;
```

`myref` can't be used where a constant expression is expected anyway, because the variable it refers to is not a constant expression. I don't see how this is different from:

```
static const int myvar = myfunc();
const int& myref = myvar;
```

The generated assemblies appears to be also the same.

Comment: In any case, the `const` in `constexpr const` is redundant. `constexpr` already implies `const`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - The `constexpr` applies to the reference, not the referent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`constexpr&` is initialized before the program start and has to bind to variables with static storage duration, which neither is necessary for `const&`.

Comment: So is it more of a restriction, without any use case? (Apart from, possibly, performance)

Comment: @A.S. it has a clear usecase of being determined at compile time ensured. Though currently compile time computations / preprocessing are limited... one has to wait till Reflection and associated tools are available to truly utilize it.

Comment: @A.S. Well such a restriction is already a use case. And as ALX23z mentioned we will benefit more in the future. Think of simpler metaprograms :)